# ordering grouped items with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code used to work for Sql Server.
But I couldnt make it work properly; statuses just wont get in order and display the latest one first.
How can I fix it?

```
<%
    SQL = "SELECT S.MEMBERID, S.StatusMessage, S.StatusPlace, S.StatusCity, S.StatusDateEntered"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATUSES S"
    SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY S.MEMBERID"
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY S.StatusDateEntered DESC"
    Set objStatuses = objConn.Execute(SQL)
%>
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that *THAT* code used to work for Sql Server.

Comment: what do you mean they 'wont get in order?' you're ordering by the correct column, assuming StatusDateEntered is a timestamp

Comment: StatusDateEntered is a datetime field. If I remove group by statement, it orders the data correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can group by one column and then select multiple columns on which you are not grouping.

Comment: This is actually valid for MySQL.  Although as @MichaelFredrickson points out, there's no way this worked on SQL Server as it looks now.  Why do you need the GROUP BY?

Comment: What results are you hoping to get?  If you're grouping my Member ID, then do you want a count?

Comment: how do you want it to be? Latest first? Or the old comes first?

Comment: latest first. Just updated my original message. Hopefully it will make it clearer.

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY (and use DISTINCT if needed), it doesn't serve any purpose here other than to confuse the results.

Comment: can I know the result after executing this: SELECT S.MEMBERID, S.StatusMessage, S.StatusPlace, S.StatusCity, S.StatusDateEntered
FROM STATUSES 
GROUP BY S.MEMBERID
ORDER BY S.StatusDateEntered DESC;

Comment: The code itself returns one data with the smalled ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael thanks a lot for your help.
I just found out about the LIMIT clause.
It did the trick too.

```
    SQL = "SELECT S.MEMBERID, S.StatusMessage, S.StatusPlace, S.StatusCity, S.StatusDateEntered"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATUSES S"
'   SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY S.MEMBERID"
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY S.StatusDateEntered DESC LIMIT 1"
    Set objStatuses = objConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't working because you're doing `GROUP` on `MEMBERID`, but you're not aggregating any of the non-grouped columns... which gives you just a random value for every other column for each `MEMBERID`... which won't necessarily be the most recent.  Next, you're ordering by this scrambled data, which isn't what you're expecting.

To fix this, you need to do a *groupwise-max*, which can be efficiently implemented as a `JOIN` to a sub-query containing the `MAX(StatusDateEntered)` for each `MEMBERID`:

```
SELECT 
    S.MEMBERID, 
    S.StatusMessage, 
    S.StatusPlace, 
    S.StatusCity, 
    S.StatusDateEntered
FROM 
    STATUSES S
    JOIN (
        SELECT MEMBERID, MAX(S2.StatusDateEntered) AS MaxStatusDateEntered
        FROM STATUSES
        GROUP BY MEMBERID
    ) S2 
        ON S.StatusDateEntered = S2.MaxStatusDateEntered
        AND S.MEMBERID = S2.MEMBERID
ORDER BY S.StatusDateEntered DESC
```

Comment: This is great but I could simply use TOP 1 with Sql Server. Can I optimize this code like that?